# Preventing infinite loop in java

Tags: java, frameworks, infinite-loop

I wanted to make a little game like robot wars in Java.

the idea is to extend my class Robot, with the custom rules, you add to it.

however, i have so things I want to prevent coders to do, like infinite loops.

I know some compilers will complain if there is an endless loop, in a Methode the requires a returning value. but I don't think all compilers will return an error on this, so I was thinking if there was a way to check this another way too?

or maybe a way to make some sort of timeout on a method?

**Update:**
Looking back to this question I posted almost 3 and a half year ago, I am no longer doing programming in Java, however still an active Programmer, and with the years, I learned how hard it is to police 3rd party code if there is no review cycle implemented.
There is no simple way to check if Code is malicious (that is why we have anti-virus programs).

To do a thing that I wanted to do, I first of need to control the entire platform I am developing too, to check for reasons the code is behaving as it is, a task that would be nearly imposable or too time-consuming.

that is why to do this more securely, the solution I reached is to use a Scripting Language that limits the user to the idea you had in mind.

Hosting a Program on servers, that everybody has access to add code to is simply not a good idea. not even with Manage Program Languages as Java and CIL, as the platforms are not checking for those specifics, it would simply take too much effort to do this.

Even though there is a way to "Sandbox" programs in Java, by using [Policies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html)
and C# have [something similar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/how-to-run-partially-trusted-code-in-a-sandbox), it would never prevent a skilled programmer to exploit or do something that was never intended.

I hope this update gives other a warning to what they are doing since I noticed this topic recently go searched a lot.

Comment: Compilers know nothing about runtime. Yes the compiler will complain of unreachable code when it can.

Comment: You can use a static counter variable and break the loop by checking counter value.

Comment: the static counter would proberly demand the counter get counted from sinde the plugin, however what if a third person made the plugin, with the idea to sabotage the game

Comment: In general, testing if a program terminates is impossible (see [wikipedia: Halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)).

Comment: so my best shot would be to run the Class Methode in a new Thread, and give it a timeout time, and terminate the Thread if the timeout is reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the context of the game. But I would like to begin this answer by saying that you cannot prevent someone from coding an infinite loop, and you cannot stop an infinite loop once it is running. As long all your code is reachable, and you return what you have to etc., Java won't help you in detecting and preventing infinite loops.

However, if you would like to execute another routine for a period of time and ensure you get access to your thread again, one way to do so is through a Future.

If you allow "other coders" to implement a Runnable or a Callable, then you can use the Future class's [get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method to cause the robot to timeout after a predetermined period of time. This will prevent infinite loops in the other thread from claiming your thread forever.

However, it is important to note that if the other Robot has an infinite loop, it may never stop running even after your timeout. Java provides no guarantee that it can stop the other thread. So when invoking such routines in your code, it is important that you know what you're invoking.

Here is some sample code which uses a Future.

```
abstract class Robot implements Runnable {

}

class SampleRobot extends Robot {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {

        }
    }

}

class RobotRunner {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public void runRobot(Robot robotToRun) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Future<?> robotFuture = executorService.submit(robotToRun);
        try {
            robotFuture.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            // This is where you would handle the timeout occurring.
        }
    }
}
```

Remember that you should not expect real-time behavior from timeouts in Java. Also remember to shutdown your ExecutorService when you're done using it.

Comment: thanks, i was thinking to do the same thing, i didn't know that java had no way to force a termination, i guess i might have to give this one up, to be fair, it had never been the intention for java to work this way

Comment: As long as everyone who uses your contract correctly abides by it, you can ensure that threads die. However, everyone needs to follow the contract. As long as you can trust them to do so, then it can work.

If you'd like to do some more reading on thread termination strategies in Java, here is what I find to be a pretty helpful and easy to understand document http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html